# Hover on element and getComputedStyle in Node.js using Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, hover, google-chrome-devtools, puppeteer

I want to hover on some element, let say `document.getElementById("abc")` and find its hover computed style.

How should I do it in Node.js using Puppeteer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following solution to iterate and hover over certain elements to obtain the computed style:

```
const elements = await page.$$('.abc');
const data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  await elements[i].hover();
  data.push(await page.evaluate(element => window.getComputedStyle(element), elements[i]));
}

console.log(data);
```